# Check If a Number Is Right-Truncatable Prime

Tags: c

i wrote this program to check if a prime number exists but it doesn't seem to work. i'm pretty new at this but i thought that checking if a number is prime and if by eliminating the last figure you still obtain a prime number. can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int n, b;
    int power;
    int temp;
    int prime=1;
    int i,j;

    do{
        printf("insert positive number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }while(n<=0);

    power=1;

    while(n>10){

        temp=n/10;
        power++;
    }
    for(j=power;j>=0;j--){

        for(i=2;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0){
                prime=0;
            }
        }
        n=n-(n/pow(10,pot));
    }

    printf("%d", prime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're never checking whether each number is prime before removing the last digit.

Comment: I do not see variable `pot` to be defined somewhere.

Comment: `pot` is probably a typo for `power`.

Comment: The first `while` loop keeps setting `temp` to `n/10`, it doesn't repeatedly divide `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary loop should be somewhat similar to this:

```
while (n > 10) {
    n = n / 10;
    if (!check_prime(n)) {
        nrt_prime_flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

where the `check_prime()` should check if the current `n` is prime or not, ie, it returns 0 if not prime.